# prevent query from using index

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a query that needs to go on EACH AND EVERY record in a table. I do have a condition `WHERE LENGTH(f1)>2`
Still, it should do a full table scan, but it seems to be using an index, which makes it actually slower.
How do I make a query not to use specific index (namely, the one on `f1`).

Comment: Are you sure the index really is the reason why it is slower? What is the output of `EXPLAIN your_query`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [index hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html):

```
SELECT ...
FROM sometable
IGNORE INDEX (`name_of_index`)
WHERE ...
```